# AWS API Gateway - Encoding

Tags: aws-api-gateway

I want to create a mock service and return a static json message. 
When I write *"Kayıt Dondurmuş"*, it becomes *"Kay?t Dondurmu?"*

How can I fix this encoding problem? I attach a sample result view to topic.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This appears to be a display issue with the console - we will look into this.

However, the actual invocation will use the correct unicode characters. I have confirmed this with your test input in test invoke as well as deployed invoke.

Thanks,
Ryan